How I do replace this type of washer supply valve?


Do I just unscrew the valve and put the new one in, or do i have to remove that silver oval thing at the bottom? IF so? how to do I remove the plastic box?
Thanks for the help!

you might not be able to unscrew the vale, without removing the copper line first, the silver part stays
